# Silent security on android

Tags: ssh, android, dns

I saw a DEFCON talk about owning back a stolen PC/Mac, with a SSHd daemon and a dynamic-ip service installed,running in background.
I was wondering if is it possible to achieve tha same results on an Android phone with root access? If yes, how?
Since Android it's not like any Linux distro,how would be possibile?

EDIT: I already know about android built-in tools, but they aren't "silent", i mean the feedback they give to the thief, if you lock or wipe or anything else on your phone,he will probably throw away ,or in a fear of getting busted, destroying it!
What i mean is something the thief can't notice and in meantime you can get informations about him.

To be clear: on Meego(debian-based)you just need to put the dynamic-ip service binary, and start it at boot. How you can achieve the same results?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to obtain remote control over? Android already has built in tools for finding and locking your device remotely, plus most people have a pin on their device so it's unlikely a thief would continue to use your device while you observe them. https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: @thexacre devicemanager it's little game compared to the possibilities that android can provide

Comment: @thexacre actually i found the app [Cerberus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsdroid.cerberus&hl=it) that does what exactly i was looking for,still, it's not a free solution, that needs an external app to send SMS-commands (and not raw one) to the stolen phone